# How to pass multiple textfieds to single Java script functions and calculate result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create an order page, where I have three input text fields on each line for each item as follow.

```
Product-Name           Qunatity  Price/item   Total Price 
checkbox-item1-name     textfield1 textfield2  textfield3 
checkbox-item2-name     textfield1 textfield2  textfield3
checkbox-item3-name     textfield1 textfield2  textfield3
checkbox-item4-name     textfield1 textfield2  textfield3
checkbox-item5-name     textfield1 textfield2  textfield3
checkbox-item6-name     textfield1 textfield2  textfield3
---                     ---         ---          ---
---                     ---         ---          ---
---                     ---         ---          ---
```

I am using following code  where I am trying to calculate Total Price by multiplying textfied1 and textfied2 and then displaying the result in textfield3.Following code work for one line or one item .I want to adjust it in way that it should work for all items without creating separate functions for each item.

```
<script>

    function calculate() {
    var myBox1 = document.getElementById('a').value; 
    var myBox2 = document.getElementById('b').value;
    var result = document.getElementById('c'); 
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
    result.value = myResult;


}
</script>

<html>
<head>
<title>New Order</title>
</head>
<body>


<div id="header">
<h1>Order Portal</h1>
</div>

<div id="items">

<form action="">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Item</th><th>Weight</th><th>Price/lb</th><th>Total Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="gjc" value="gjc">Item1</td>
<td><input type="text" name="gjq" id="a" size="6" onchange="calculate()"><label for="weight">lb</label></td>
<td>$<input type="text" name="gjqp" id="b" size="6" onchange="calculate()"></td>
<td>$<input type="text" name="gjtp" id="c" size="6"></td><br>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="bf" value="bf">Item2</td>
<td><input type="text" name="bfq" id="a1" size="6" onchange="calculate()"><label for="weight">lb</label></td>
<td>$<input type="text" name="bfqp" id="b1" size="6" onchange="calculate()"></td>
<td>$<input type="text" name="bftp" id="c1" size="6"></td> 
</tr>
</table>
</form>


</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use ONLY unique values of id attributes on page.

2) Something like this:

```
var
    form   = document.querySelector('#your-form-id'),
    inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]'),
    result = 0,
    p,
    n;

for (p = 0, n = 1; n < inputs.length; p += 2, n += 2) {
    result += (
        (Number(inputs[p].value) || 0)
        *
        (Number(inputs[n].value) || 0)
    );
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<script>
function calculate(input) {
    var parentEl = input.parentNode.parentNode;
    var myBox1 = parentEl.querySelector('.myBox1').value; 
    var myBox2 = parentEl.querySelector('.myBox2').value; 
    var result = parentEl.querySelector('.result'); 
    var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
    result.value = myResult;
}
</script>

<form action="">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Item</th><th>Weight</th><th>Price/lb</th><th>Total Price</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="gjc" value="gjc">Item1</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="myBox1" name="gjq" id="a" size="6" onchange="calculate(this)"><label for="weight">lb</label></td>
  <td>$<input type="text" class="myBox2" name="gjqp" id="b" size="6" onchange="calculate(this)"></td>
  <td>$<input type="text" class="result" name="gjtp" id="c" size="6"></td><br>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="bf" value="bf">Item2</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="myBox1" name="bfq" id="a1" size="6" onchange="calculate(this)"><label for="weight">lb</label></td>
  <td>$<input type="text" class="myBox2" name="bfqp" id="b1" size="6" onchange="calculate(this)"></td>
  <td>$<input type="text" class="result" name="bftp" id="c1" size="6"></td> 
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/qhxyvyfn/ for working example